# Finding out the messages count in thread message queue from a memory dump

Tags: c++, debugging, winapi, windbg

I aware of the fact that it’s not possible to determine how many messages are in the thread queue at any given time with any sort of Win API calls. I’ve an application that doesn’t work because PostMessage fails sometimes (possibly due to the queue growing to 10000, although I don’t see how could it grow so big). It’s an intermittent issue and I have several memory dumps taken at exactly the moment when it happens.
Obviously the queue has to be somewhere and this article explains how to get it http://moyix.blogspot.com/2008_09_01_archive.html

> Each thread in Windows (represented by the _ETHREAD strucutre) has a
>   field in its Thread Control Block (or Tcb, which is a _KTHREAD) called
>   Win32Thread. This field points to a data structure, _W32THREAD, which
>   is defined in the kernel-mode portion of the Windows graphical
>   subsystem, win32k.sys. You can actually examine the _W32THREAD
>   structure by issuing "dt win32k!_W32THREAD" in WinDbg; however, if you
>   start reverse engineering win32k.sys, you'll quickly find that the
>   information given there is far from complete. In fact, _W32THREAD is a
>   much larger data structure, which includes information about the
>   current desktop, keyboard layout, installed window hooks, and, most
>   importantly for us, the input message queue. In Windows XP SP2, the
>   message queue is found at offset 0xD0 of _W32THREAD, and looks like:
>
> ```
> typedef struct _MSG_QUEUE  {   PMSG_QUEUE_ENTRY Head; 
> PMSG_QUEUE_ENTRY Tail;  unsigned long NumberOfMessages;   } MSG_QUEUE;
> ```

Basically I’m trying to find a pointer MSG_QUEUE (which will give me NumberOfMessages, plus I can enumerate them starting from Head). However it doesn't look I can find pointers to any of _ETHREAD, _KTHREAD and _W32THREAD by analyzing memory dump. Where exactly are they stored, are they in process memory space? Do I have to run in kernel mode? Do I need to load symbols for win32k.sys? Anything else I need to do? Thanks.

Comment: Just curious: what does say GetLastError() when PostMessage Fail?

Comment: Usually it's ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_QUOTA, but in the latest report there is no error (well it's 0x12 probably from some earlier error of something else)

Comment: The KTHREAD and related structures are in kernel mode, but memory dumps capture only user mode. So the information is not in the dump file.

Comment: I'd spend my energy trying to find why the UI thread is deadlocked.

Comment: UI thread is not deadlocked, it just seems like the other threads are posting too many messages to the main thread. In fact my temp workaround is to keep calling PostMessage in the loop until it eventually succeeds (obviously this solution is not great and won't work if UI thread wants to post to UI thread)

Comment: To Raymond: So does it mean that the techniques in the article only apply if there is a full kernel dump?

Comment: There is a programm which installs a driver to give you the required info... http://blog.airesoft.co.uk/2009/11/jumping-the-queues/  also you could use a "live memory dump" ;)

Comment: Which operating system do you use? It was much easier on Windows XP than it is now on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a full answer with all WinDbg commands, but maybe still helpful.

The message queue is only accessible in kernel mode, so you need a kernel dump or use SysInternals livekd.
Use the -y switch to set the symbol path.

```
livekd -y srv*d:\debug\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

Once you are in kernel mode, find the process you want to debug

```
!process 0 0 executable.exe
```

Then get the threads of the process

```
!process <process> 4
```

All threads which have Win32Thread not equal to 0 are potentially interesting.

The blog post [Jumping the queues](http://blog.airesoft.co.uk/2009/11/jumping-the-queues/) describes the rest for Windows 7.
I couldn't immediately follow and the article does not actually describe which WinDbg commands to use. I remember it was much easier on Windows XP.